# TypeError: Member "encodeCall" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in abi

Tags: compiler-construction, solidity, smartcontracts, remix, hardhat

[image]

```
function encodeCall(address _newOwner, uint _sigRequired) external view returns (bytes memory) {
    // Typo and type errors will not compile
    return abi.encodeCall(this._addSigner, (_newOwner, _sigRequired));
  }
```

```
pragma solidity >=0.8.0 <0.9.0;
```

I was trying to compile and deploy the code.
I get an error even though the abi library should be available globally without importing it.
The hardhat compiler is also configured properly.
It does get compiled and deployed on Remix.
Must be an issue with the compiler

Comment: Probably related to the version, try changing the version of Solidity in your compiler configuration to 0.8.0 and see if that resolves the issue, if so, you may need to update your code to use the latest version of Solidity

Answer (score 1):

`abi.encodeCall()` was introduced in v0.8.11.

*Source: missing in [v0.8.10](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.10/units-and-global-variables.html?highlight=abi.encodeCall#abi-encoding-and-decoding-functions), documented in [v0.8.11](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.11/units-and-global-variables.html?highlight=abi.encodeCall#abi-encoding-and-decoding-functions).*

Since your `pragma` statement allows to compile this contract with any 0.8 version, it depends on your local Hadhat config which Solidity version it uses (within these boundaries).

Assuming your compiler uses version older than 0.8.11, this function is not yet available.

---

Solution: Either specify a newer Solidity version in your `pragma` statement or update the version in your [Hardhat config](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/docs/config#solidity-configuration).

```
// .sol file
pragma solidity 0.8.17;
```

```
// hardhat config
module.exports = {
    solidity: "0.8.17",
};
```

Comment: I thought it was introduced in version 0.6.0, and I had specified my hardhat config to have 0.8.4 version. But when I tried version 0.8.17, it did work. Thanks